# SQLite file not updating after table creation

Tags: java, sqlite, maven, tomcat, spring-web

Ok, this is the situation. I reused a piece of code from a different project where I checked if a table existed in a certain sqlite db file. If not, it would create the table.

The code worked then and I didn't add major changes to the file, so I am confused that no data is written to the file.

Before I ran the code I had to create an empty database file, which I put src/main/resources, named example.db

```
public class DBStuff{
    protected Connection c = null;
    private final String fileName;

    public DBStuff(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        checkDB();
    }

    protected void startConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:" + fileName);
            c.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBStuff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    protected void closeConnection() {
        try {
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBStuff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void checkDB() {
        startConnection();

        checkTable("firsttable", "CREATE TABLE firsttable"
                + "(id                 TEXT    PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL, "
                + " stuff              TEXT                 NOT NULL)";

        checkTable("secondtable", "CREATE TABLE secondtable "
                + "(id              TEXT    NOT NULL, "
                + " stuffId         TEXT    NOT NULL, "
                + " specificStuff   TEXT    NOT NULL, "
                + " CONSTRAINT pk_idstuffId PRIMARY KEY (id,stuffId),"
                + " CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES firsttable(id))");

        closeConnection();
    }

    private void checkTable(String dbName, String sql) {
        try {
            ResultSet rs;
            boolean exists = false;
            DatabaseMetaData md = c.getMetaData();
            rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString(3).equals(dbName)) {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!exists) {
                Statement stmt;
                stmt = c.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                stmt.close();
                c.commit();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBStuff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I created a DBStuff object using

```
DBStuff dbstuff = new DBStuff("example.db");
```

I have verified with print statements that the tables are found when checkDB is run a second time (by printing out `rs.getString(3)`).

However when I look in the database file (in all possible locations I could think of, in `src/main/resources/example.db`, `target/classes/example.db` and inside the warfile in `WEB-INF/classes/example.db`), the file is not updated. It is still 0 bytes in size in all those locations.

What am I doing wrong? Why are the tables not written to these files?

I ran the code both with and without this in my pom file

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the file was actually located in `target/ProjectName-x.x.x/WEB-INF/classes/example.db`

Tip for me next time: use the search functionality in my file browser. It finds things that you might never find.